# Not able to click on the nested anchor element using xpath of selenium webdriver

Tags: ruby, xpath, selenium-webdriver

***Please find the Html below :***

```
<table class="data" id="filteredTable" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="1">
<tbody>

<tr class="rowLight">
  <td class="lt4"><input name="ids" value="att1" type="checkbox"></td>
  <td><a hfref= " link1" > foo </a>
  </td>
  <td>item1</td>
  <td>item2</td>
  <td>item3</td>
</tr>

<tr class="rowDark">
  <td class="lt4"><input name="ids" value="att2" type="checkbox"></td>
  <td><a hfref= " link2" > boo </a>
  </td>
  <td>item1</td>
  <td>item2</td>
  <td>item3</td>
</tr>


<tr class="rowLight">
  <td class="lt4"><input name="ids" value="att3" type="checkbox"></td>
  <td><a hfref= " link3" > bar </a>
  </td>
  <td>item1</td>
  <td>item2</td>
  <td>item3</td>
</tr>
```

Now I need to click on the link of `bar`. But my below `Xpath` not helping me to get into the bar as well. So any help how to be done the same.

I didn't give the `html` for the part `//form[contains(@name,'filterset_FilterSetListForm')]/table[contains(@class,'contentBody')]/tbody/tr/td/table[contains(@class,'content')]/tbody/tr/td/`. <~~ till this I am correct. Confusion start  after ***`<tr>`*** from here `/table[contains(@id,'filteredTable')]/tbody/tr`

***Part-II:***

When there will be a match say `bar` , can their associated `check box (s)` be clicked?

Any help in this regard?

I am using ***`selenium -web driver`*** with `Ruby 1.9.3` .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the `a` element this way

`/table[contains(@id,'filteredTable')]/tbody/tr/td/a[contains(text(),'bar')]`

or if you want an exact match to the link text

`/table[contains(@id,'filteredTable')]/tbody/tr/td/a[text()=' bar ']`

Comment: Does it look for each `<tr>` ?

Comment: Not sure what you mean with 'each <tr>' but in your sample it will find the a in the last <tr>. For your second question, if you mean the difference between the two alternatives, the first one checks if the text in <a> contains 'bar' and the second one checks for an exact match of what is in your sample: ' bar '.